# How to Install Copay desktop wallet in Ubuntu?

Tags: wallet, copay

Could someone publish a step by step instructions to install, in a simple way, the Bitcoin desktop wallet Copay?

I have read the "instructions" published in their Github account and believe me, it's not user friendly:

> Desktop versions (Windows, OS X, Linux)
>
> Copay uses NW.js (also know as node-webkit) for its desktop version.
>   NW.js is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js.
>
> -Install NW.js on your system from nwjs.io
>   -Run grunt desktop

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not instructions to install it. These instructions are for building Copay on your system.

Here are the instructions for end-users (non-developers):

> 1) Download the latest binary

You should visit its [Copay releases page](https://github.com/bitpay/copay/releases/latest) on GitHub and choose the ZIP file for Linux.
[image]

After you download it, unzip it and make sure you moved its folder to somewhere you won't forget.

> 2) Run it

Open the Linux Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal if you're on Linux Mint or Ubuntu)

Open Copay's folder (which you just unzipped and moved).

There should be ~ 20 files and folders in that folder.

Find the file named "Copay" (without quotes and its icon may look like a document), drag that file onto Terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now its GUI should open. Please note that you have to do Step 2 everytime you want to run it.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, could you please complete it adding how to config the icon in the left bar? thank !

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest binary from GitHub and choose the ZIP file for Linux
2. unzip (for example to the directory `Downloads`)
3. open the Linux Terminal
4. go to the folder `(position yourself)/BitPay-linux` using command `cd`
5. type command `"./Bitpay"`

So, you need to type something like this:

```
user@User-945GCM-S2w:~$ cd Downloads
user@user-945GCM-S2w:~/Downloads$ cd BitPay-linux
user@user-945GCM-S2w:~/Downloads/BitPay-linux$ ./BitPay
```

---

where `user@user-945GCM-S2w` is your username

Answer (score 0):

Define variables

```
COPAY_REPO="bitpay/copay"
LATEST_TAG=`curl https://api.github.com/repos/${COPAY_REPO}/releases/latest -s | jq .name -r`;
```

Download and uznip release

```
wget https://github.com/${COPAY_REPO}/releases/download/${LATEST_TAG}/BitPay-linux.zip && unzip BitPay-linux.zip && rm -rf BitPay-linux.zip && cd BitPay-linux
```

Run wallet

```
./BitPay
```